# Passing shared memory array to worker pool in Python

Tags: python, array, multiprocessing

I'm working with big 2d `numpy` arrays, and a function that I need to iterate over each row of these arrays.

To speed things up, I've implemented parallel processing using Python's `multiprocessing` module. Each worker of the pool gets an array index, which is used to read the data from the shared array, and after the function is executed, overwrite the data in the shared array on the same location.

The function returns the modified values as well as a processing parameter, which in turn is also stored in a separate 1d shared array.

So my questions are:

I've read many times that it's not particularly safe to have multiple processes reading and writing data from a shared array. Until now, things have just worked fine. Should I change my approach? Are there real concerns that things could not work as intended?

If the above mentioned approach isn't safe and/or practical, what would be a good alternative approach to implement this kind of processing, where I need to access shared arrays, for both reading and writing?

Of course, I'm also grateful for any other constructive comment  on my code!

Here's a working example. In this case the function is merely generating a random integer by which the raw data is then multiplied and overwritten in the shared array. The generated integer can be seen as the processing parameter, which I need to store in the second shared array.

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes
import array
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
from contextlib import contextmanager, closing


def init_shared(ncell):
    '''Create shared value array for processing.'''
    shared_array_base = mp.Array(ctypes.c_float,ncell,lock=False)
    return(shared_array_base)

def tonumpyarray(shared_array):
    '''Create numpy array from shared memory.'''
    nparray= np.frombuffer(shared_array,dtype=ctypes.c_float)
    assert nparray.base is shared_array
    return nparray

def init_parameters(**kwargs):
    '''Initialize parameters for processing in workers.'''

    params = dict()

    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        params[key] = value
    return params


def init_worker(shared_array_,parameters_):
    '''Initialize worker for processing.

    Args:
        shared_array_: Object returned by init_shared
        parameters_: Dictionary returned by init_parameters
    '''
    global shared_array
    global shared_parr
    global dim

    shared_array = tonumpyarray(shared_array_)
    shared_parr = tonumpyarray(parameters_['shared_parr'])

    dim = parameters_['dimensions']

def worker_fun(ix):
    '''Function to be run inside each worker'''

    arr = tonumpyarray(shared_array)
    parr = tonumpyarray(shared_parr)

    arr.shape = dim

    random.seed(ix)
    rint = random.randint(1,10)

    parr[ix] = rint

    arr[ix,...] = arr[ix,...] * rint

##---------------------------------------------------------------------- 



def main():
    nrows = 100
    ncols = 10

    shared_array = init_shared(nrows*ncols)
    shared_parr = init_shared(nrows)

    params = init_parameters(shared_parr=shared_parr,dimensions=(nrows,ncols))

    arr = tonumpyarray(shared_array)
    parr = tonumpyarray(params['shared_parr'])

    arr.shape = (nrows,ncols)


    arr[...] = np.random.randint(1,100,size=(100,10),dtype='int16')


    with closing(mp.Pool(processes=8,initializer = init_worker, initargs = (shared_array,params))) as pool:

        res = pool.map(worker_fun,range(arr.shape[0]))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # check PARR output
    print(parr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

An the output:

> array([ 7.,  3.,  1.,  4.,  4., 10., 10.,  6.,  4.,  8., 10.,  8.,  8.,
>           5.,  2.,  4.,  6.,  9.,  3.,  1.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  5.,  7.,  7.,
>           4.,  8.,  2.,  9.,  9.,  1.,  2., 10.,  9.,  9.,  6., 10.,  7.,
>           4.,  8.,  7.,  2.,  1.,  7.,  5.,  2.,  6.,  9.,  2.,  8.,  4.,
>           5., 10.,  3.,  2.,  9.,  1., 10.,  4.,  5.,  8., 10.,  8.,  8.,
>           7.,  2.,  2.,  8.,  1.,  2.,  6.,  2.,  5., 10.,  8.,  6.,  5.,
>           4.,  3.,  5.,  9.,  3.,  8.,  5.,  4.,  1.,  3.,  7.,  2.,  4.,
>           2.,  7.,  8.,  9.,  9.,  6.,  4.,  6.,  7.], dtype=float32)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To address your immediate concerns, the code is safe. Each worker operates on its own (sub)set of data. Nothing is really shared, so there is no data race.
- It is unclear why the worker function calls `tonumpyarray` on the objects which already are numpy arrays.
- I strongly advise against using random numbers in testing. It is pretty much impossible to say wether the results are correct.

Comment: Although using a PRNG with fixed seed does provide some validation ability.

Comment: Thanks! Glad the approach is OK. The duplicate `tonumpyarray` seems to be indeed without use ... but it didn't throw any error, so I never noticed. And regarding random numbers, point taken. I just used them here to simulate some function where the array values are overwritten ... I guess using the index would have been just as fine. Thanks again!